# How to make image fit in container?

Tags: html, css, image, css-position

I'm trying to use Bootstrap grid system with rows each has 4 column contains image, but the image size is big and it gets over its container, so I set image `position: absolute` and `div` `position: relative` but it still doesn't work. Is there any way to make the image fit the div container with container's size?

```css
.sec5row {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 sec5row">
      <img class="filter" src="https://placehold.it/40" alt="f1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 sec5row">
      <img class="filter" src="https://placehold.it/40" alt="f1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 sec5row">
      <img class="filter" src="https://placehold.it/40" alt="f1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 sec5row">
      <img class="filter" src="https://placehold.it/40" alt="f1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: just use img {width:100%}

Comment: img{ max-width: 100%;} might work. Or maybe even img{width:100%;} if you want it at 100% all the time.

Comment: Or possible even better add the bootstrap class img-responsive to the image (assuming you use bootstrap based on the way you create columns).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the below code to fit image inside the responsive div

```
 .filter {
     width:100%;/*To occupy image full width of the container and also fit inside the container*/
     max-width:100%/*To fit inside the container alone with natural size of the image ,Use either of these width or max-width based on your need*/
    height:auto;
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me why height :auto? sorry I'm so new.

Comment: @pexichdu To maintain the aspect ratio of the image based on the width or else the image will look stretched since we have given width as 100%

Answer (score 3):

I think the bootstrap class ".img-responsive" solves your problem. So try something like this:

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="resources/images/f1.jpg" alt="f1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="resources/images/f2.jpg" alt="f1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="resources/images/f3.jpg" alt="f1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="resources/images/f4.jpg" alt="f1">
            </div>
     </div>
 <div>
```

It sets the style of your image to "max-width: 100%;" and "height: auto;" which should be exactly what you need. There should be no need for any additional css.

Answer (score 2):

Add css to your code

```
#img {
    width: 100px;//change px size
    height: 100px;//change px size
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: why #img ?? There is no ID with for img tag

Comment: make a simple id=" "  that it it wont affect anything.

Comment: or use class like ".filter"

Answer (score 0):

> Just add class="img-responsive" to your img tag...it works fine